# Proving Gauss' theorem for nat in Coq

Tags: coq, proof

I'd like to prove Gauss' theorem for `nat`.

In plain (non-precise) language it says: if `a` divides `b*c` and none of `a`'s factors are in `b` then they must all be in `c`.

```
Require Import NPeano. 
Theorem Gauss_nat: forall (a b c:nat), gcd a b = 1 -> (a | (b*c)) -> (a | c).
```

The theorem is already defined for integers `Z`, see [here in the Coq manual](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.ZArith.Znumtheory.html#Gauss).  But I need it for `nat`.  The recommendations I have gotten so far is to use Bezout's lemma which states that

```
Lemma Bezout: forall (a b c:Z), Z.gcd a b = c -> exists u v, u*a+v*b=c.
```

However, I can't use it directly for `nat`s since the coefficients `u` and `v` might be negative and thus it doesn't hold for `nat`.

Is there another proof that does not use integers in the proof?

EDIT:

As was pointed out in a comment by  Mark Dickinson, the theorem and lemma are already in Coq's library. They are in `NPeano`, named `Nat.gcd_bezout` and `Nat.gauss`.

Comment: You could prove and use a nat-based version of Bezout: `forall (a b:nat), exists u v, u*a = gcd a b + v*b`.

Comment: That would be perfect! Could you give an "Answer" with a Coq prof of a nat-based Bezout and how Gauss_nat follows from it?

Comment: (Or  at least `bezout_nat`, I was able to prove Gauss_nat by using it....)

Comment: It looks as though these results are already in the [standard library](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Numbers.Natural.Abstract.NGcd.html): look for `gcd_bezout_pos_pos`, `gcd_bezout`, and `gauss`.

Comment: Proof is here: https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/V8.4/theories/Numbers/Natural/Abstract/NGcd.v#L176-L188

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to obtain the result for `nat`, and not really avoid the use of `Z`, you can just reuse the proof in the standard library. Here's a sketch of how you could proceed, relying on two auxiliary lemmas:

```
Require Import NPeano.
Require Import ZArith.
Require Import ZArith.Znumtheory.
Require Import Omega.

Close Scope Z_scope.

Lemma Zdiv_Ndiv a b : (a | b) <-> (Z.of_nat a | Z.of_nat b)%Z.
Proof. Admitted.

Lemma Zgcd_Ngcd a b : Z.of_nat (gcd a b) = Z.gcd (Z.of_nat a) (Z.of_nat b).
Proof. Admitted.

Theorem Gauss_nat a b c : gcd a b = 1 -> (a | (b*c)) -> (a | c).
Proof.
rewrite Zdiv_Ndiv, Zdiv_Ndiv, Nat2Z.inj_mul.
intros H1 H2.
assert (H3 : Z.of_nat (gcd a b) = 1%Z) by (rewrite H1; reflexivity).
rewrite Zgcd_Ngcd in H3.
apply (Gauss _ _ _ H2).
now rewrite <- Zgcd_1_rel_prime.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful - I quess one occasionally wants to borrow theorems back and forth between Z and nat.  (It seems quite ugly to have to deal explicitly with all the Z.to_nat and Z.from_nat and Nat2Z.inj_mul,  but perhaps it is better than "magic" transformations...)